# Wordpress add homepage slider

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm fairly new to wordpress so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

**I want to put a slider on my homepage.**
I know how to put it in a page using the shortcode, but I don't know where I can set it on the main page. The theme has it's own slider that shows the posts but I want a slider with 2 images that I created showing under the header.

The slider plug-in I am using is Slider WD: https://wordpress.org/plugins/slider-wd/

The theme I am using is Activello: https://colorlib.com/wp/themes/activello/

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you've tried and why it hasn't worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your theme folder, find the file **header.php**. That's where you should insert your short code. Like this:

```
do_shortcode( 'your_short_code_here' );
```

To make sure that it displays only on the home page, you may insert it this way:

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    do_shortcode( 'your_short_code_here' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you purchase this theme 
as this theme also support Slider you don't need to add any plugin for that
good thing about that you should read documentation of this theme.On wordpress every theme have its own methodology to use it.reading documentation is good habit for learning